# Copy git repository to offline machine and pushing/pulling via memory-stick

Tags: git, offline-mode

I need to work on an offline machine, where I cannot access my repository. Now I also don't want miss out on using Git altogether.

Questions:

- What is the best way to copy my repository onto an offline machine via memory-stick?
- Is there a way to copy patches via the filesystem?

---

Edit: I should have stated, that I will have to hand over the memory stick to an administrator who will do the copying for me, i.e. I cannot mount the stick with my user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To copy a complete Git repo, you just have to copy the folder `.git`; it contains everything. Git uses safe file names and ignores time stamps inside of the repo, so this data is safe from the usual file system quirks.

On the target machine, create a folder, copy the `.git` folder inside. Now `git checkout <branch>` will get you a working copy.

If you want to move patches back and forth instead of the whole repo, then `git format-patch <branch>` creates them. The command will create all patches necessary to update a remote repo (i.e. the output will contain everything that hasn't been pushed, yet). you can also give it commit IDs (= start with this commit) or ranges.

To apply them, use `git am < 0001....` on the remote repo.

Related:

- http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/patch-workflows

Comment: Good advice. And after the initial copy you can e.g. use `format-patch` and email the patches to yourself to avoid having to involve your sysadm for keeping your offline repo in sync.

Answer (score 7):

For copying your repo to the memory-stick, simply use `git clone`, and then use `git pull` to update it.

E.g., on your online computer, with the memory-stick mounted, do

```
cd <memory-stick-mount-point>
git clone <local-path-to-git-repo>
```

now the `<local-path-to-git-repo>` will be the `origin` remote for the repo on your usb-stick, so later you can
simply use `git push/pull` (when mounted on the online machine) to sync your offline work.

The git repo on the memory stick is self-contained, so now you can work against that on any computer, and then sync as above when you mount it on your online machine.

**Edit**, re: not being allowed to mount the stick yourself:

If you can ask the admin to `git clone` the repo onto the memory stick it is fine. Otherwise, your admin can simply copy the entire project.git directory (if it's a bare repo) or project/.git (otherwise) to your memory stick, and you can work against that, the thing to watch out for is that the remotes, etc. will be those of the online machine.

Then, pulling is not a problem, but pushing may need a further work-around if you don't trust your sysadm to resolve your merge conflicts for you. 
If you have your own branch(es) then merging is not a problem. 
Otherwise
to do merges "offline", you could have *two* offline copies of the repo, one that you work on, and one that is your "origin", and when you get back, ask the sysadm to git pull to the "origin" repo, and then, on an offline computer, do the merge between the two memory-stick repos, and then ask the sysadm to merge your origin repo into the online one.

This feels a bit brittle and open to race conditions, though, so I'd really try to create separate branches before "going offline".

Comment: I should have explained that I cannot mount the stick myself. I need to ask the admin to copy the contents onto the local filesystem. Does that affect the git repo?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. But Aaron's answer is more concise. Just note that a directory containing a bare repo is the same as the .git directory inside a repo with a working directory.

Comment: No. Every repo is a complete repo. You can push changes from one repo to another and viceversa with pull.

Comment: Yes, I simply meant to stress that a bare repo will not have a `.git` directory in it, it **is** the .git directory but may have any name.

Answer (score 7):

The command `git bundle` is designed for this. For example, to clone the master branch of the repository offline,

```
cd my-repository
git bundle create offline-repos master
```

That will store the entire `master` branch in a file named `offline-repos`. Copy the file to another computer. On that computer, type

```
git clone -b master offline-repos new-repos
```

That will create the folder `new-repos`, checked out from `offline-repos`. The bundle file you cloned from will be treated as a remote repository. You can even create a bundle that store the changes since a ref, as in:

```
git bundle create offline-repos e45ad329..master
```

If you replace the bundle file `offline-repos` with a bundle containing new changes, you can `git pull` from it, as in:

```
cd new-repos
git pull
```